# Capture value of a hidden input element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input element:

```
<input type="hidden" id="input_2_204_data" name="input_2_204_data" value>
```

I need to capture an event when it is changed and value is not empty. I have looked over older SO's questions, however nothing seemed to work.

Here is the latest snippet I have come up with, however it does not work either, and there are no errors in console:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $sign = jQuery('[id$=input_2_204_data]');   

    $sign.on("change", function(){
        alert('hey');
    });
});
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: There's no event raised when the value of an `input` is changed programmatically. You should call a function (or trigger an event manually) on the element when needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $sign = jQuery('#input_2_204_data');   
alert($sign.val())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong selector to target element, You need to use ID selector `#` here to target element by id:

```
var $sign = jQuery('#input_2_204_data');   
$sign.on("change", function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Copied and pasted the snippet, however it does not log the value, netiher logs any error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct selector `#input_2_203_data`. Using [`.change()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change) works just fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var $sign = jQuery('#input_2_204_data');   

  $sign.change(function() {
    if($sign.val() != '') {
      alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    }
  });
});
```